# SCLAlertView Button

Tags: ios, swift

When I used third party SCLAlertView there was a problem actually there is a problem that is I want to perform some action when the button will pressed but there is just the customization properties but I am wondering for the action scope can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this

```
 let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
        showCloseButton: false // if you dont want the close button use false 
    )
    let alertView = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
    alertView.addButton("Ok Pressed") {
        print("Ok button tapped")


    }
alertView.showSuccess("Success", subTitle: "")
```

you get the detail example for [add buttons](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift#add-buttons) and hide [default close buttons](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift#hide-default-close-button) property in [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift)

Answer (score 0):

I never used this library, however if we take a look at the Github repo of the project (https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift) we will see the following example:

```
alert.addButton("Show Name") {
    print("Text value: \(txt.text)")
}
```

Where `print("Text value: \(txt.text)")` gets executed after clicking the button.